# How can I install git on unix using wget?

Tags: git, unix, raspberry-pi3, yocto

How can I install git on unix using wget?

I tried

```
 wget http://github-media-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/osx/git-credential-osxkeychain.
```

Then I moved it to /usr/bin but git config command failed.

I tried also 
`wget --no-check-certificate -q https://github.com/joyent/node/tarball/v0.7.1`

> wget: error getting response: No such file or directory

I am working on Yocto poky 2.1.3 distro image on raspberrypi and trying to install git. I don't have apt package on my bin. So only option left is wget.

Comment: You cannot expect a random binary to work at any "unix". You need a package prepared for your distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend to start using available way of install packages within the **Yocto**, there is dedicated variable which is allows to add packages in order to install into image [IMAGE_INSTALL](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.1/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-IMAGE_INSTALL), just add this line into Your *conf/local.conf* file:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " git"
```

Comment: @AkashBhardwaj if this is possible please accept my answer as best answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

My guess is that you will have to download from sources, build and install

```
wget https://github.com/git/git/archive/v2.17.1.tar.gz
tar zxvf v2.17.1.tar.gz
cd git # or whatever directory the tar.gz file contains
./configure
make
make install
```

Or something along those lines.

Comment: Installing from sources is hard and requires **a lot** of dependencies!

Comment: I agree. But given that there's no _apt_ available... anyway.